# Used display property to make h1 an in-line block, but now font-size has no effect

Tags: css

Even when set to 1px, text doesn't change size, but keeps all other properties. There is an image next to it.

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #F16059;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 1px;
  margin: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="img/chef-hat.png" alt="chef hat">
  <h1>Recipe Collection</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: The code you have given works absolutely fine so please have a look in your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see exactly what is setting the CSS for your h1.